# Slight inaccuracy in Rogers – Ramanujan Identities?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

The Rogers–Ramanujan identities  are two of the most remarkable and important results in the theory of  q-series. 
$$  1+ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{q^{n^2}}{(1-q)(1-q^2)...(1-q^n)} = \prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(1-q^{5n-1})(1-q^{5n-4})} $$

$$  1+ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{q^{n^2+n}}{(1-q)(1-q^2)...(1-q^n)} = \prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(1-q^{5n-2})(1-q^{5n-3})} $$

A simple consequence of the Rogers–Ramanujan identities involves partitions of the integers. The number of partitions of n denoted p(n) grows
exponentially with n.
The Rogers–Ramanujan identities imply two
theorems for partitions of n subject to some
simple restrictions. One of these may be
stated as follows:
The number of partitions of n such that all parts differ by at least 2 is
equal to the number of partitions of n such that all parts are congruent
to 1 or 4 modulo 5.

For example, if we take n = 9, then out of
the 30 unrestricted partitions only 5 are of
the first type:
9, 8+1, 7+2, 6+3,
5+3+1
and five are of the second type:
9, 6+1+1+1, 4+4+1,
4+1+1+1+1+1,
1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1.

Now let us take n=18 and consider the number of partitions of the first type. These are:
18,  17+1 , 16+2 ,  15+3 , 14+4 , 13+5 , 12+6 , 11+7 , 10+8 , 14+3+1 , 13+4+1 , 12+4+2 , 12+5+1 , 11+5+2 , 11+6+1 , 10+5+3 , 10+6+2 , 10+7+1 , 8+6+4 , 9+7+2 , 9+6+3  , 8+6+3+1 , 9+5+3+1 ,
There are 23 partitions of first type in total. 
What about the number of partitions of the second type ? There seems to be just 22 partitions of the second type ?!  These are:
16+1+1 , 14+1+1+1+1 , 11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1 , 9+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1 , 6+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1 , 4+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1 , 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1 , 14+4 , 11+4+1+1+1 , 9+4+4+1 , 9+4+1+1+1+1+1 , 6+4+4+4 , 6+4+4+1+1+1+1 , 6+4+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1 , 4+4+4+4+1+1 , 11+6+1 , 6+6+6 , 4+4+4+1+1+1+1+1+1 , 4+4+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1 , 9+6+1+1+1 , 6+6+4+1+1 , 6+6+1+1+1+1+1+1 ,

Similarly, according to my calculations,  when n=23 , there are 46 partitions of first type in total, but only 45 partitions of the second type.  Have I made an error in both my calculations ?
Assuming that I have counted them correctly , I make the following conjecture: The number of partitions of n such
that all parts differ by at least 2 is
equal to the number of partitions of
n such that all parts are congruent
to 1 or 4 modulo 5. This is true for all integers  except the following : 18 , 23 , 28 , 33 , 38 , 43 , 48 , 53 , 58 , .....For these integers (which form an arithmetic progression ), the number of partitions of n such
that all parts differ by at least 2 is always one more than the number of partitions of n such that all parts are congruent to 1 or 4 modulo 5 .

Comment: $18=9+9$ maybe?

Comment: @Oscar Lanzi . No  because all parts  must differ by at least 2 . 9 and 9 do not differ by at least 2 !!

Comment: I meant parts congruent with $\pm 1 \bmod 5$.

Comment: @OscarLanzi.  You are right.  9+9  is a valid partition. I made a mistake and you have found it !! Well done !!  I probably made a mistake when n=23  as well .

Comment: With 23 I do get 46 second type partitions.  Rogers and Ramanujan win.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably we are just missing some partitions in our count.  Counting things is a lot tougher than it sounds.  In the comments we found that $18=9+9$ was missing from the second set of partitions and when we include that, the R-R identity comes out true.

For $23$ here is my second set:

$21+1+1$

$19+4$

$19+1+1+1+1$

$16+6+1$

$16+4+1+1+1$ (5)

$16+1+1+1+1+1+1+1$

$14+9$

$14+6+1+1+1$

$14+4+4+1$

$14+4+1+1+1+1+1$ (10)

$14+1+...+1$

$11+11+1$

$11+9+1+1+1$

$11+6+6$

$11+6+4+1+1$ (15)

$11+6+1+...+1$

$11+4+4+4$

$11+4+4+1+1+1+1$

$11+4+1+...+1$

$11+1+...+1$ (20)

$9+9+4+1$

$9+9+1+1+1+1+1$

$9+6+6+1+1$

$9+6+4+4$

$9+6+4+1+1+1+1$ (25)

$9+6+1+...+1$

$9+4+4+4+1+1$

$9+4+4+1+...+1$

$9+4+1+...+1$

$9+1+...+1$ (30)

$6+6+6+4+1$

$6+6+6+1+1+1+1+1$

$6+6+4+4+1+1+1$

$6+6+4+1+...+1$

$6+6+1+...+1$ (35)

$6+4+4+4+4+1$

$6+4+4+4+1+1+1+1+1$

$6+4+4+1+...+1$

$6+4+1+...+1$

$6+1+...+1$ (40)

$4+4+4+4+4+1+1+1$

$4+4+4+4+1+...+1$

$4+4+4+1+...+1$

$4+4+1+...+1$

$4+1+...+1$ (45)

$1+...+1$ (46)

Rogers and Ramanujan win.